# Send multiple file http flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, multipartform-data

I have a list that contains File from camera. And I want to send all of the list to server. How can I reach that?

```
Future<void> addServiceGrTransaction({List<File>? dataFile}) {
   var url = '$baseUrl/add-service-gr-transaction';
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   token = prefs.getString('token');

   var header = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': '$token'
   };

   Map<String, String> obj = {'data': body.toString()};
   Map<String, String> objFile = {'file': dataFile.toString()};
   var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url))
     ..headers.addAll(header)
     ..fields.addAll(obj)
     ..fields.addAll(objFile);
   for (File file in dataFile!) {
     request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', file.path));
   }

   var streamedResponse = await request.send();
   var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   } else {
     throw Exception('Error');
   }
}
```

can I get that with this?

Comment: According to what have implemented so far, what's the issue?

Comment: `MultipartRequest` is used for that exact purpose, what's not working then?

Comment: Please be more explicit about what sort of error you're getting from the server. One thing that comes to mind immediately is that the different files might need different names (i.e. use a for i=0;i<count;++i) 'file$i' type of structure. But you could also upload the files individually. However, this is going to be 100% dependent on your server's file upload functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is how you can update your code for it to work properly as expected.

- While the philosophy is nice and workable, there are some minor errors that causes the code to not be working properly
- First, the function `Future<void> addServiceGrTransaction({List<File>? dataFile}) {` is missing `async` keyword but it does contain asynchronous tasks
- The `Content-Type` should be set to `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json` because you're sending files in the request, not JSON data.
- The response was correctly obtained, but the code can be simplified by directly awaiting `request.send()` and using `http.Response.fromStream()` in a single line.
- So based on my understanding of what you're trying to achieve, this is how you can update your function or method....

```dart
Future<void> addServiceGrTransaction({List<File>? dataFile}) async {
  var url = '$baseUrl/add-service-gr-transaction';
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? token = prefs.getString('token');

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': '$token',
  };

  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  for (File file in dataFile!) {
    var stream = http.ByteStream(file.openRead());
    var length = await file.length();

    var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename: file.path.split('/').last);

    request.files.add(multipartFile);
  }

  var response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // When the response status code is `200`, things went well.
  } else {
   // Otherwise, something went wrong! You can try to wrap statements in a try-catch bloc, for better errors handlings
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}
```